# Is it right to create a new instance of a service layer within an entity object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, domain-driven-design, solid-principles

I'm writing an application that takes a list of guessed names (let's call it `entry`), then takes a list of random names (`nameList`) and checks in `nameList` how many names `entry` got right and then returns a classification based on the result (e.g. WINNER1). This app should be able to allow the implementation of another type of game. Each entity object controls the capturing of the names and getting the classification (I'm not too comfortable with that but I'm not allowed to change that). I have created a service class which implements a generic service class (which has a getClassification method) as below..

```
public class NamesService implements GenericService {

    public String getClassification(String[] entry, String[] nameList) {
        // detailed implementation of getClassification for Names.java
        }
}
```

So Names.java will create a getClassification method which will call NamesService.java. I had to create a global instance of NamesService in the Names.java class to be able to call getClassification from its service class. Does it make a difference to create a global or local variable, or is it wrong to instantiate NamesService?

```
public class Names {

    NamesService service = new NamesService();

    // define other attributes and behaviours

    public String getClassification(String[] entry, String[] nameList) {
        service.getClassification(entry, nameList);
    }
}
```

I have written it out this way because I want another game, say Numbers.java, to be able to provide its own implementation of getClassification by using its NumbersService to implement GenericService.

Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way? I am trying to follow the DDD pattern and SOLID design principles.

One more thing, is it necessary to implement this using springboot? I'm not creating any rest interface so I'm not sure if springboot is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the right way to do it or is there a better way? I am trying
>   to follow the DDD pattern and SOLID design principles.

Services have as goal to perform the processings.
While in DDD you don't want to have *services* but you want that objects collaborate between them to perform the processings and actually this is what you did. So you are on the right way : you made  `Names` and `NamesService` to collaborate between them. But note that you should avoid the `service` suffix but favor a name that conveys better the domain, maybe `Classification`.

> Does it make a difference to create a global or local variable, or is
>   it wrong to instantiate NamesService?

If you want to reuse `NamesService` somewhere else, dependency injection is better such as :

```
public class Names {

    private NamesService service;
    // automatically injected with Spring
    public Names(NamesService service){
       this.service = service;
    }
    ...
}

@Component
public class NamesService implements GenericService {...}
```

If you want to unit test Names, providing a constructor (or a setter) for the dependency is also advised.

> One more thing, is it necessary to implement this using springboot?

You can use Spring Boot for many reasons as benefiting from dependency injection, the transaction management, the consistency between the dependencies. `Service` and `RestController` are not the single reasons to use Spring and Spring Boot.

Comment: this is super helpful! Thank you so much! Will rename service class and add dependency injection. Really appreciate your help

Comment: @joyidahosa Great if it could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to mix *data* with *business logic*. In your services you will implement the business logic that your flux of information will go through before it reaches its final state and is ready to be stored. At this point your information will be mapped to the entity, also said, the persistent representation of the data.

So basically, entities should be about representing a persisted object along with its properties, possibly adding some (basic) methods related to the meaning of such properties, and they should not implement complex business logic processes.